# Is it possible to search with in an uploaded pdf or google doc for keywords?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the situation:

I have a pdf and google doc in my drive list of documents. I would like to build an interface that could search through these documents for keywords and return the document name and possible preview of the text that matched the search parameters. Is this or some variation of this possible?

Regards,

Shawn

Comment: The answer is certainly yes... Document class contains the tools you'd need but I'm not sure you'll find a 'ready made' app that does it nor someone that will write the code for you... have you tried something yet ?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. Naturally I don't want someone to write the code for me. I find that ready made stuff really does not fit what I am looking for. I had a look at the Document class documentation. Unfortunately I often find Google's documentation to be unclear and lacking examples. Certainly not all of it, but a lot of it seems to be incomplete. I just wanted to make sure the possibility existed before I spent time on an idea that in the end may not  have been possible.

Answer (score 0):

Getting text from a Google Doc is simple:

```js
// Get text from GDOC  
var gdocDoc = DocumentApp.openById(gdocFile.id);
var text = gdocDoc.getBody().getText();
```

The pdfToText() utility from [Get pdf-attachments from Gmail as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613809/getting-certain-pdf-attachments-from-my-gmail-as-text/26623198#26623198) uses the advanced Drive service and DocumentApp to convert PDF to Google-Doc to text. You can get the OCR'd text this way, or save it directly to a txt file in any folder on your Drive.

```js
// Start with a Blob object
var blob = DriveApp.getFilesByName("my.pdf")[0];

// filetext will contain text from pdf file, no residual files are saved:
var filetext = pdfToText( blob, {keepTextfile: false} );
```

Once you have the text, a search for keywords becomes dead easy!

```js
if (filetext.indexOf( keyword ) !== -1) {
  // Found keyword...
}
```